# XeLaTeX changes " to ”

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Whenever I enter a QUOTATION MARK (U+0022), like in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
This is "in quotes"
\end{document}
```

I end up with:

[image]

That wrong symbol there is a RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U+201D).

<sub>This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.10.13)</sub>

Comment: Try with `` instead of "

Comment: That yields “ (U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK), but it's kind of tangential to my question. Also, I don't mind this behavior because I usually don't use `` in text and also it's one of the "classic" workarounds before we had XeTeX.

Comment: Do you need other TeX ligatures to work, like ``, '', --, ---, etc.?

Comment: Oh just saw your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid this mapping like this. But this will also disable the other "tex" mappings like  `--` to endash:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
This is "in quotes" -- ---
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative is to use `\textquotedbl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
This is \textquotedbl in quotes\textquotedbl\  -- ---

This is in "quotes".
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be better to explicitly use `Mapping=` instead of an empty feature set to make clear what specifically makes this work?

Comment: `Mapping` wouldn't work with lualatex. I personally wouldn't need to reset the quote style at all like this, I never use quote signs directly but use `\enquote` of csquotes.

Comment: In hindsight this mapping probably should have been left out of the `tex-text` mapping / `tlig` feature... oh well :)